# How do I cut this material to put in a coach light

Tags: lighting, stone, cutting

I'd like to put in a coach light just like the one below on the other side of the garage. The garage isn't finished, so the wiring will be easy. But I'm not sure how to cut through this thick stone facade to put in an electrical box. What tool would be best for this job?

[image]

Comment: i would drill the corners and chisel the middle, unless you have bigger power tools than I...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Home Depot or Lowes or any construction retail store and ask for a "masonry hole saw" that you can put in an electric drill. You can buy any size you want. I checked with my local Home Depot (on line) and got prices of about $25.00 for a 1" and up to $60.00 for a 4-1/8". They can be used for wet or dry drilling in almost any masonry surface. I have used them for cutting holes in both brick and concrete.

Comment: Can I use it with a regular cordless drill, or do I need a hammer drill or something more powerful? Also, since the box is rectangular I imagine the best approach is to get a size small enough for me to drill multiple times to approximate the rectangular shape?

Comment: You can use the cordless drill (if you have a good one) but go slowly. Keep a spare battery charging at all times. Don't us the hammer action.    That will loosen the stone. I would use the hole saw size just slightly larger than the overall octagon size.  The canopy of the fixture should cover the hole.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense. That answered another question I had, about what size box to get, but the octagon makes sense. Then fill in the sides with brick mortar.

Comment: you might want to get a $20 corded drill from harbor fright for the occasional hi-torque / work jobs...